# Objects in anonymous functions

Tags: javascript

Take a look at the 2 lines below.

```
foo = ({ data: { one, two }}) => {alert(one.type); alert(two.type);}
foo( /* What goes here*/ );
```

What would I put in the () on the second line to alert "Hello" in the first alert() and "World" in the second alert()?

Comment: foo({data: {one: {type: "Hello"}, two: {type: "World"}}})

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the foo function with an object that has data key. Data also is an object with two keys **one** and **two**

```
foo({
    data: {
       one: {type: 'one'},
       two: {type: 'two'}
    }

})
```

What you need to understand is that the foo component is using object destructing